# Using HP port replicator, when laptop is closed image on monitor reduces in size

Tags: external-display

I am Using HP port replicator, when laptop is closed image on monitor reduces in size. How can I set things up so that image remains full screen when laptop is closed? Laptop & monitor are both hp's. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to lack of points, but i assume you have already tried changing the resolution once the lid is closed. usually this would store the settings and next time you close the lid, it should remember it.

But if this is not the case, i believe HP (and other vendors) uses DisplayLink software to display the video through USB. 
Try to download the latest DisplayLink driver from the site: 
http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/downloads.php

This should help.